# Unable to lose jComboBox in a jTable focus

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, jcombobox

I have a jTable that has a jComboBox column. However I had an issue where I couldn't get the jComboBox to show unless you first click on it. Other people have had the [same problem](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1221919), [it seems](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1363986).

So I then learned I needed to make a CellRenderer besides the CellEditor. And so I did...

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends JComboBox<CustomItem> implements TableCellRenderer{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
        if(isSelected){
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else{
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        setSelectedItem(value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

By the way, I am also using a ComboBoxRenderer because I need it to display text while containing an item.

```
public class MyComboBoxRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus){
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if(value != null){
            CustomItem customItem = (CustomItem) value;
            setText(customItem.getText());
        }
        if(index == -1){
            CustomItem customItem = (CustomItem) value;
            setText("" + customItem.getText());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

And now it works! It does show the jComboBox in my jTable by default **BUT** now each jComboBox on each row has permanent focus! And only the first one I click on actually displays the menu. The rest are 'selected' but they do not respond.

**Edit:** Here is how I create the table.

```
private void initializeTable(){
    JTable jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dtm.addColumn("one");
    dtm.addColumn("two");
    dtm.addColumn("three");
    jTable1.setModel(dtm);

    JComboBox<CustomItem> items = new JComboBox<>();
    items.setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer());
    items.add(new CustomItem(1, "soup", false);
    items.add(new CustomItem(33, "sauce", false);
    items.setSelectedIndex(0);

    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(items));
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
}
```

Comment: Create and post a simple [sscce](http://sscce.org), please.

Comment: I will try to do so, but in the meantime I provided my table initialization method.